# Unity Not Calculating Float with division

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make something in Unity to find the multiples of a number. The way I am trying to find this is I have a for loop going through the number and if the number / i is equal to Mathf.Round(number / i) then I count it as a multiple but, it just counted every single number and when I tried Debug.Log the number / i it only gave me the result as an int. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AIpatternPredict : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<int> attacks = new List<int>();
    public int lowerScore;

    void Start()
    {
        List<int> multiples = new List<int>();

        for (var i = 1; i < attacks.Capacity; i++)
        {
            float g = attacks.Capacity / i;
            Debug.Log(g);
            if (Mathf.Round(g) == g)
            {
                multiples.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float g = attacks.Capacity / i;`

Your `attacks.Capacity` is an `int` and `i` is an `int`. So it's division with ints.

Change to
`float g = (float) attacks.Capacity / i;` to change it to division with floats. This trick is called type casting. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Answer (score 1):

For comparing whether one int is a multiple of another, use the remainder (mod) operator.

4 % 1 = 0, the remainder of 4/1.  4 % 2 = 0, 4 % 3 = 1, 4 % 4 = 0.

So if the remainder is == 0, the second number is a multiple of the first.

```
        if ((attacks.Capacity % i) == 0)
        {
            multiples.Add(i);
        }
```